# Anaconda installed without conda.exe

Tags: python-3.x, installation, windows-10, anaconda, conda

I had missing `conda.exe` in `Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts` folder, so `conda` command doesn't work. This is not PATH problem. After that I have uninstalled anaconda, rebooted and installed just downloaded last version of anaconda. Installation was without admin rights. After that I still have conda missing in that folder.

What can I do? Is where a way to install conda eventually? Is it better to open an issue?

*Windows 10, anaconda 5.01*

PS I have previously installed Anaconda. Which I believe was installed with admin rights to whole users. Can it cause such problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been multiple reports of incomplete Windows Anaconda installations with Anaconda v5.0.1. There is a current workaround that you could try to see if this resolves the problem: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting#cannot-open-anaconda-prompt-after-installation

Uninstalled and installed with miniconda. Then installed with conda Anaconda, everything is fine now

Comment: I had the same issue even with the miniconda workaround

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in installation.

Issue: anaconda.exe file not found

**Solution worked for me : Installed with admin rights and anaconda.exe was found in installation folder and startup menu.**

Status : Resolved